# Gerar QRcode de um ficheiro

Tags: php

Crio ficheiros em PHP, e queria adicionar uma imagem QRCode de cada ficheiro, para fazer o seu download. Os ficheiros são PDF e SVG.

Comment: Crio um ficheiro com o fwrite e depois utilizo <a href=\"$namefile\">$namefile</center></a> para o download.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/)

> PHP QR Code é uma biblioteca open source (LGPL) para a gerar imagens QR Code.
>
> Baseado na biblioteca em libqrencode C, fornece uma API para criar imagens de código de barras QR Code (PNG, JPEG graças a GD2).
>
> Implementado puramente em PHP, sem dependências externas (exceto GD2 se necessário).

**Exemplo**

```php
include('qrlib.php');

// saída direta para o navegador da imagem com o QR Code na forma de PNG
QRcode::png('Dados aqui que pode ser o caminho completo para o ficheiro');
```

Para que a saída seja aplicada na página, podes usar algo tipo:

```
// tag <img/> com caminho para o PHP que gera o QR Code
echo '<img src="qrcode_do_meu_ficheiro.php" />';
```

Podes consultar os inúmeros [exemplos](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/index.php) diretamente no site da biblioteca.